# handle firebase error without crashing nodejs server

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've got this code below that fetches once from firebase on nodejs. I'm purposely throwing an error and attempting to catch it, however, the error isn't being handled and my server keeps crashing and my catch statement isn't being executed.

> FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. Error:
>   Article is not found

```
var ref = fdb.ref("Emojis");


ref.once("value", function (data) {
    // do some stuff once
    throw Error('Article is not found');
    console.log(data.val());
}).catch(error => {

    console.log('an error happenned')
});
```

I also tried this code and the error is still not handled:

```
ref.once("value", function (snapshot) {
    throw Error('Article is not found');

    console.log(snapshot.val());
}, function (errorObject) {
    console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

Comment: Your catch isn't executed because the error you're throwing is happening in the success callback. For your catch to be triggered the error has to happen during the execution of the `once` method, not after it has already succeeded

Comment: that makes sense thank you